# UI elements don't re-position on opening keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am currently busy learning how to use Firebase and I've built a very simple UI for my experiment. Unfortunately, when I test the app and I want to fill in the EditTexts with the keyboard, the keyboard is appearing over the UI elements. I can't figure out why this is happening. I've tried out ConstraintLayout and RelativeLayout, but the problem is on both layouts.

Before filling in EditText

[image]

During filling in EditText

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: share layout xml file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

to your activity in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

add this line of cdoe which will scroll the layout to above the soft keyboard.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

or,
write your layout inside a scrollview

Comment: it's also possible to do it in the manifest. adding android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" to the activity

Comment: @PietroScarampella adding that line of XML to the Manifest fixed my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Obdam i'll add as a reply so. Have  a nice day!